# How to achieve the effect that pull down to load more data in flutter project，but not pull down to refresh data？

Tags: flutter

I am writing a chat application, but I have a problem to achieve the effect that pull down to load more data.

I want to achieve the effect:

1. The chat data that user send will dispaly in the ListView form up to down.
2. When user pull down the ListView ,the old chat data will load ,but not display immediately. When user scroll the ListView ,the old char data should be displayed.

Snippet:

```
class _List3PageState extends State<List3Page> {
  List<String> _stringList = [];
  int i = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      _stringList.add('chat data');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('pull down to load more data'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _stringList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  child: Text(_stringList[index]),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                List<String> oldData = [];
                oldData.add('chat old data $i');
                i += 1;
                oldData.add('chat old data $i');
                i += 1;
                oldData.add('chat old data $i');
                i += 1;
                oldData.add('chat old data $i');
                i += 1;
                _stringList.insertAll(0, oldData);
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Text('load old chat data')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can surround your listview with a gesturedetector and then use the onVerticalDragDown event.